Why is `Color pumpkin(245, 118, 26)` not valid?
With this code
sf::Color pumpkin(245, 118, 26);

I get this error:
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   28 |         sf::Color pumpkin(245, 118, 26);
      |                           ^~~

This on the other hand works fine:
sf::Color pumpkin = sf::Color(245, 118, 26);

Why am I getting an error for the first form?
I found this answer which seems to suggest that my first form should work as I expect it to. Isn't it just like the ent3 case in said answer?
Edit:
pumpkin is a class variable. Thus this is a duplicate of Why can't member initializers use parentheses?
Minimal reproducible example:
test.h:
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

class Test
{
    sf::Color test(1,2,3);
};

test.cc:
#include "test.h"

CMakeLists.txt:
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_executable(test)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system webp webpdemux)

target_sources(test PRIVATE test.cc)


Please post a complete [mre].

Can pumpkin be a unexpected (function) MACRO?

Both lines are generally fine, at least in some contexts, but there are context where not both are fine. I can make guesses as to which context you are trying this in, but we shouldn't answer questions based on guesses what the actual question is.

@Jarod42: I don't have any macros.

What compiler are you using, and which C++ standard are you specifying?

C++ 17 with g++ (GCC) 13.3.1 20240522 (Red Hat 13.3.1-1)

Is pumpkin a field in a struct/class?

This is weird, I suggest inspecting preprocessor output with -E.

What happens when you type: sf::Color pumpkin{245, 118, 26}; instead of sf::Color pumpkin(245, 118, 26);

Are you trying to initialize class members at the point of declaration? If so, you need to use list initialization sf::Color pumpkin{245, 118, 26};

@drescherj, Gene: Interestingly, it works with curly braces. But I have no idea why.

@user1785730 -- because it's not a valid initialization of class members.

Just to confirm, is pumkin a class member variable?

@Gene According to the documentation Color does have a constructor like this: Color (Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue, Uint8 alpha=255). Why does it matter if they end up being class members?

@NathanOliver yes

@NathanOliver Thank you. I can confirm that that's the same problem. Now I need to study the answer, at first glance I didn't get it.

@user1785730 The long and short of it is that with the way the grammar of the language is set trying to make type name(intializer) work isn't going to happen.  So brace initialization and the type name = initializer initialization were the work arounds to allow in class member initialization.  Unfortunately initialization is a major pain point in C++.  If you've got an hour, here is a great watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Note: with a [mre] (MRE) this question would have been answered (or dupe-closed) within 2-3 minutes. Normally I'd rant about how making the MRE would have likely ended early with you spotting the problem, but this isn't one of those cases. If you didn't know this bit of nasty before making the MRE, odds are you wouldn't suddenly learn it part way through.

@user4581301 Actually, I did create an MRE. But by the time it was ready, my question was already closed. I decided to make a new one with my MRE, but then NathanOliver had already pointed me to another relevant question.

Closed questions can be reopened if the issue raised are addressed. Creating a new question with the requested fixes is not good SO etiquette.

@drescherjm: sorry for the late reply, it was late for me yesterday. I've now added the MRE to the question.

Why can't member initializers use parentheses?

@user12002570 Exactely. I have that already in my question.

Question is on it's way to being re-opened. It'll be closed again, but this time with a valid duplicate. May the question live a long and fruitful life as a signpost.

Upvoted to restore the balance of nature. And, voted to close, since we all agree it's a dupe. On a side note, may I encourage the OP to use brace-initialization henceforth?

@Super-intelligentShade: Thanks. I was actually thinking about, to what I should default now. I was opting for the copy constructor / assignement form, like in my first variation. That looks like in other languages like Java and should be universally understandable. On the other hand, the speaker in the video NathanOliver linked is promoting the brace-initialization form, like you. Not sure if I like that, because it is in fact a list initialization, which to me makes more sense in case  of something like a vector.

Unfortunately, SO doesn't like style questions. Could you maybe point me to an in-depth discussion of the matter?

@user1785730 Brace initialization (aka uniform initialization) was introduced in C++ to solve the problems like yours. It is the standard now. If you grab any recent book or watch a video from eg CppCon you are almost guaranteed to see it being used.
